# How to pause and resume a multithread perl script?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have written the perl script to pause and resume.When the user enters <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it has to pause and on pressing <kbd>c</kbd> it should resume.  But is not working properly as expected.  Can anyone help me on this what mistake i am making:

```
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Suspend;
use Lens;


$SIG{'INT'} = 'Pause';
#$| = 1;


print chr(7);
my $nthreads = 64;
my @thrs;


for(1..$nthreads)
{
   print "START $_ \n";
   my ($thr) =  threads->create(\&worker, $_);
   push @thrs ,$thr;
}
$_->join for @thrs;
exit;

sub worker
{
   my $id = shift;
   my $tmp;
    my  $lens = Lens->new("172.16.1.65:2000");
    die "cannot create object" unless defined $lens;
    die "cannot connect to XRay at " unless defined $lens->open("172.16.1.65:2000");
   for(1..100000)
   { 
      print "Thread $id \n";

   }
   print "$id>LOAD EXIT\n";
}

sub Pause 
{
   sleep(1);
   print "\nCaught ^C\n";
   print "Press \"c\" to continue, \"e\" to exit: ";
   $_->suspend() for @thrs;
   while (1) 
   {
      my $input = lc(getc());
      chomp ($input);
      if ($input eq 'c') {
      #clock($hour,$min,$sec);
      $_->resume() for @thrs;
      return;
   }
   elsif ($input eq 'e') {
      exit 1;
   }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't been too specific as to how it's "not working properly". But I would suggest looking at using `Thread::Semaphore` for a 'suspend' mechanism.

I would also suggest not using `signal` and instead doing something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore;

use Term::ReadKey;

my $nthreads = 64;

my $thread_semaphore = Thread::Semaphore->new($nthreads);


sub worker {

    for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
        $thread_semaphore->down();
        print threads->self->tid(), "\n";

        sleep 1;
        $thread_semaphore->up();
    }
}

for ( 1 .. $nthreads ) {
    threads->create( \&worker );
}

my $keypress;
ReadMode 4;

while ( threads->list(threads::running) ) {
    while ( not defined( $keypress = ReadKey(-1) )
        and threads->list(threads::running) )
    {
        print "Waiting\nRunning:". threads->list(threads::running) . "\n";
        sleep 1;
    }
    print "Got $keypress\n";
    if ( $keypress eq "p" ) {
        print "Pausing...";
        $thread_semaphore -> down_force($nthreads);
        print "All paused\n";
    }
    if ( $keypress eq "c" ) {
        print "Resuming...";
        $thread_semaphore -> up ( $nthreads ); 
    }
}
ReadMode 0;

foreach my $thr ( threads->list ) {
    $thr->join();
}
```

It'll 'suspend' by setting the semaphores to zero (or negative) and relies on the threads checking if they should be stopping here or not.

I think the root of your problem though, will probably be signal propagation - your signal handler is global across your threads. You might find configuring `$SIG{'INT'}` for your threads *separately* will yield better results. (E.g. set the signal handler to 'IGNORE' at the start of your code, and set specific ones in the thread/main once the threads have been spawned).